# How to get twitter access token in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, twitter

How can I get users `access token` and `access token secret` in the background by the `username` and `password`?

I try(according of the twitter documentation):

```
app.get('/token', function(req, res){
    tweet.post('/oauth/access_token', function(err, data, response){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

And it response with the error:

```
{ [Error: Sorry, that page does not exist]
   message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist',
   statusCode: 404,
   twitterReply: '{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}',
   code: 34,
   allErrors: [ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ] }
 undefined
```

What is wrong? Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the /token endpoint?
I can't find it in the documentation https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview
Plus, if you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter remember that it puts api.twitter.com/1.1/ in front of all the endpoints you pass to it.
So /token becomes api.twitter.com/1.1/token and /oauth/access_token becomes api.twitter.com/1.1/oauth/access_token

If you like to use username and password I think you should use https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/xauth

I think you should watch at https://github.com/request/request it has a couple of interesting examples with twitter

Answer (score -1):

I have used passportjs as a reference when working with google and facebook (I did not use twitter).
have a look at https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/blob/master/lib/strategy.js for the implementation of the strategy to get access to twitter.

Comment: Please do not provide link only answers.